# qual o link devo usar no meu artigo da pagina de eventos? para ela abrir e carregar individualmente?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, link

Olá galera  to  com uma  duvida  que ta me tirando o sono.

> Na minha pagina ***index.html*** tenho uma `< section >` chamada **EVENTOS**, e também tenho uma pagina chamada ***eventos.html***
>
> Na ***eventos.html*** tenho alguns `< article >` cada "artigo" linkado para a pagina ***eventos.html***

O problema é que todos os  meus artigos aparecem todos juntos na pagina de ***eventos.html*** tipo eu clico no artigo 1 e aparece todos os outros um abaixo do outro! 
 *** 
eu queria saber se tem alguma maneira de fazer com que cada artigo carregasem ao clicarem nele***

**ou seja ao clicar no meu artigo ele carregar e abrirem na mesma pagina ? que no caso e a pagina de EVENTOS** ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<section id="eventos-index" class="pg-eventos" />
<!--sesao de eventos index -->


<h1>EVENTOS </h1>

<a href="eventos.html#evento-jigante" title="jigante em mutuipe ba">

  <article class="fotos"><img src="_imagens/eventos/jigante.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <hgroup>
      <h2>Gigante 18/01/2018 mutuipe BA</h2>
    </hgroup>
  </article>
</a>

<a href="eventos.html#santinha" title="baille da santinha saj">
  <article class="fotos"><img src="_imagens/eventos/santinha.jpeg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <hgroup>
      <h2> Baille da santinha 18/01/2018<br>SAJ BA</h2>
    </hgroup>
  </article>
</a>


<section class="eventos" alt="eventos do vale">

  <h1>EVENTOS</h1>

  <a href="#evento-gigante">
    <article class="eventos" id="evento-gigante">
      <img src="_imagens/eventos/jigante.jpg">
      <p class="desc-eventos">
        gigante<br> bloco nana com leo santana
        <br>Local campo Grande Salvador <br> Data 18/01/18.<br> Hora. 21:00hs <br> Valor. Individual. 190.00 reais <br> Casadinha. <br> 340.00 reais <br> 5 x no cartão. <br> Shopping Mega China.</p>
    </article>
  </a>
```

Comment: Se você não fez uma página de detalhe para cada evento, não tem como fazer isso. Está usando apenas HTML?

Comment: to usando HTML e CSS ! mas o site nao ta hospedado ainda nao sera que pode ser isso tambem ? página de detalhe para cada evento?  como e isso brother?

Comment: No seu caso, como você já está na página de eventos, utilize apenas o link da âncora, sem o nome do arquivo, assim não vai recarregar a página.

Comment: Faz uma pagina para cada evento.. Assim quando for clicar no link ira redirecionar para a pagina do evento

Comment: @FelipeAcelinocomo é que  eu faço essa pagina de detalhe ?

Comment: @Olimpio como eu faço essa pagina de detalhe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que entendi é que você deseja o documento **eventos.html** carregue um artigo diferente, de acordo com o link clicado na página **index.html**.

No entanto, se esse for o objetivo, não é possível atingi-lo somente com HTML e CSS.

Dessa maneira, você terá que estudar outras tecnologias que permitem dinamizar o conteúdo. Assim, um exemplo seria aprender banco de dados e PHP, para conectar seu site ao CMS Wordpress.

**Links úteis:**

- [Curso de PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7KzJ7e6EAc&list=PLHz_AreHm4dm4beCCCmW4xwpmLf6EHY9k) by Curso em Vídeo;
- [Curso de Banco de Dados](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofktsne-utM&list=PLHz_AreHm4dkBs-795Dsgvau_ekxg8g1r) by Curso em vídeo.

Comment: ta ok muito obrigado ! vou dar uma estudada  aki